# Which technology to use in an electronic kiosk: Wi-Fi or Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, wifi

I have a doubt in which technology to use in either case, Wi-Fi or Bluetooth. I have an electronic kiosk in which I want the user to connect his/her phone with the electronic kiosk and share information through an app in the phone and the electronic kiosk.

Reading about the Bluetooth technology, always in the first connection, you have to pair your phone with the device. Imaging pairing a lot of new users every day! What a pain! And as far as I know this is done through the OS in the device and the phone, not through the app.

And about the Wi-Fi technology, I imagine the electronic kiosk can act as a server and accept multiple connections through an open wireless network, without the need of pairing like in the Bluetooth technology. Still I don’t know the problems regarding doing this programmatically in the app in the phone and in the app in the device.

What do you think is the best option for this application?

Answer (score 0):

WiFi might be better, not only because of its larger bandwidth. If you want everything done automatically, here's a possible way.

First, set up a WiFi AP on your kiosk, with a fixed name, for example kioskAP. Then the app in the phone keeps connecting to the AP named "kioskAP". All these can be done through API or commands. Once connected, the phone gets an IP address a.b.c.d, and knows that the kiosk has IP address a.b.c.1. Now the phone is able to talk to kioskAP with this IP address.